# Is it important to open a pull request after just pushing changes with new branch?

Tags: git, github

Every time I push my changes on GitHub, I always see a popup with a "compare & pull request" notification on top of my repo.

So is it important to open a pull request on every change?

Comment: That depends entirely on the workflow and branching model you are using.

Comment: Generally no. Pull Requests should be done for a single feature, mostly related to an issue which is then resolved by the pull request. As the content of a PR is mostly made up of multiple commits and you can push after every commit if you want, you don't necessarily need to do a PR every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a message to inform you:

- this possibility exists
- of the default target branch name (should you open a PR)

But you remain in charge, and decide when what you have pushed should be considered for a PR or not.

And you don't have to go to GitHub for that: if you install the [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/), you can open a PR directly from your console, with [`gh pr create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create).

> When the current branch isn't fully pushed to a git remote, a prompt will ask where to push the branch and offer an option to fork the base repository. Use --head to explicitly skip any forking or pushing behavior.
>
> A prompt will also ask for the title and the body of the pull request.
> Use `--title` and `--body` to skip this, or use `--fill` to autofill these values from Git commits.